# How to show alert in a jsp from a servlet and then redirect to another jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, alert

**I tried this but does not display the message only redirects**
**login.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="Login_Servlet" >
  <input name="idUsuario" type="text"/>
  <input  name="password" type="password" />
  <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

**Login_Servlet**

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String userid= request.getParameter("idUser");        
String password = request.getParameter("password");
Login_Service login_Service = new Login_Service();
boolean result = login_Servicio.aut(userid, password);
Usuario user = login_Servicio.getUsuariosByUsuario(userid);
    if(result == true){
       request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);            
       response.sendRedirect("vistas/Inicio.jsp");
    }
     else{
       out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
       out.println("alert('User or password incorrect');");
       out.println("</script>");
       response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");    
    }
```

**Is it possible to display a message like this? if so I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: you declare login_Service but use login_servicio, is this a typo?

Comment: itself is a mistake I went to post it when it's okay `boolean result = login_Service.aut(userid, password);`and  `Usuario user = login_Service.getUsuariosByUsuario(userid);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may possibly do this:

```
else
{
   out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('User or password incorrect');");
   out.println("location='index.jsp';");
   out.println("</script>");
}
```

*Edited: 20<sup>th</sup> March 2018, 08:19 IST*

**OR** *without using js*

```
else {
   out.println("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=index.jsp'>");//redirects after 3 seconds
   out.println("<p style='color:red;'>User or password incorrect!</p>");
}
```

Comment: I will try this way and if I do not I will try with ajax but now the question is how I redirected to another jsp to have the same behavior I will try this way and if I do not I will try with ajax but now the question is how I redirected to another jsp to have the same behavior `response.sendRedirec();`

Answer (score 4):

You could redirect to your jsp but pass a message to be displayed:

```
request.setAttribute("loginError","Incorrect password");
```

Then in the jsp:

```
 <c:if test="${not empty loginError}">
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
         alert("${loginError}");
    }
    </script>
</c:if>
```

The not empty syntax allows checking for the existence of a parameter

Comment: I must say I don't think users really like having alerts all the time, probably better to have a message displayed on the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
pw.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
pw.println("alert('Invalid Username or Password');");
pw.println("</script>");
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("userlogin.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

From Servlet, redirect to another jsp normally as you do, and on jsp "onload" event call a javascript function which will give you the alert you need.....

Comment: so I had it but if someone reloads the page or give me back again and the message should no longer appear