# Redirecting the page with Servlets Java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, redirect

I have a **jsp** page with a form that when it’s submitted goes to a **Servlet** that inserts the form data into the database.

When the data is inserted into the database, I’m trying to get the browser back to my jsp page and show a javascript alert saying that the data was inserted successfully, my code is the following:

```
    RequestDispatcher rd;
    if(dao.insertClient(client)) { 
        rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pages/clients.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
        out.print(
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                + "alert("Client inserted successfully!");"+
            "</script>"
        );           
    }
```

This code is doing exactly what I want, but this method **getRequestDispatcher()** redirects the page to the servlet itself, and the URL is like http://localhost:8080/Servlet, this way I **can’t** access any intern link of the page, since the links to the other pages obviously are outside of the servlet context, and the glassfish returns the 404 error.

Instead of using getRequestDispatcher(), I’ve tried using the **response.sendRedirect()**, this way I can insert the data into the database and access the intern links, but the javascript alert **isn’t** shown.

Somebody has a suggestion on how I can redirect the page to the **clients.jsp** and display the javascript alert?

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using Ajax to send request to your servlet. This way you don't have to navigate away from the jsp

Comment: Why don't you put a script into the session, and after you re-direct you can read it from there?

Comment: Can you pass me the basic syntax to put the script into the session? I've googled but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try another approach :

Set parameter from servlet like this :

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
if(dao.insertClient(client)) { 
     rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pages/clients.jsp");
     request.setAttribute("isSuccess", "success");
     rd.include(request, response);
}
```

access the parameter in jsp to check whether to show alert or not.

```
<%
   String result = request.getParameter("isSucess");
   if("success".equals(result)){
%>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
      alert("Client inserted successfully!");
   </script>
<%
  }
%>
```

Comment: Actually the code above shows the alert, but the problem is that the getRequestDispatcher redirects the page to the servlet and not to the jsp, if I use the other method response.sendRedirect() it redirects to jsp and I can access internal links, but the alert isn't shown, thanks!

Comment: @emersondms : take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176684/how-to-show-alert-in-a-jsp-from-a-servlet-and-then-redirect-to-another-jsp