# how to get current logged in role by alert box in jsp and spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp

*I have a jsp with roles like this*

```
<div class="col-md-1 form-group inner-addon left-addon">
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${role == 'Incident Incharge' || role == 'Incident DeptHead' || role == 'Incident User'}">

       <input type="text" id="empName" name="empName" data-val="${list.empName}" value="${list.empName}" autocomplete="off"  /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="uempId" name="uempId" data-val="${list.uempId}" value="${list.uempId}" autocomplete="off"  /> 

      </p>

  </c:when>
```

*How to alert the role in my script like*

```
<script>
if(role=='Incident Incharge')
     {
         alert(role)
     }
```

Comment: One of the examples, you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176684/how-to-show-alert-in-a-jsp-from-a-servlet-and-then-redirect-to-another-jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store the value of `${role}` as a hidden html field (or some other dom element)
then you can access it from javascript

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myrole" name="myrole" value="${role}" />
```

JS (jquery)

```
var role = $('#myrole').val ();
```

or

```
var role= document.getElementById('myrole');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are cheking the Role? the best practices is a taglib powred by Spring Security :

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('Incident Incharge')">

......

</security:authorize>
```

if there is a need to alerting a  `$(role)` you can store it on the hidden input and acces to this hidden with JS