# How to generate an alert box from java servlet to a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

upwd --> refers the entered password in login page in HTML page named (index.html)

rpwd --> refers retyped password in the login page in the same HTML page

```
    //-->Code in servlet
    if(upwd.equals(rpwd))
     {
           //database connectivity of a login form 
     }
    else
     {
         response.sendRedirect("index.html");
          //index.html is the name of the html page where im redirecting. 
     }
```

Since I m doing the validation in the servlet.Now,how can I generate an alert box in HTML(index.html) stating that password didn't matched from Servelet.

Comment: Is your question how to display an alert with Javascript? Or is your question how to send information from server to client (so the client knows *what* to display in the alert)?

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways from here to generate `alert` with message

**First way** : put the below html code in index.html file

```
alert("password didn't matched !");
```

**Second way :** Generate a alert from servlet and then redirect to your HTML page

```
 out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.println("alert('password didn't matched ');");
 out.println("</script>");
 response.sendRedirect("index.html");
```

you can even read : [How to show alert in a jsp from a servlet and then redirect to another jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176684/how-to-show-alert-in-a-jsp-from-a-servlet-and-then-redirect-to-another-jsp/24176753) hope this helps

Comment: Well it's not working for me,eventhough it's redirecting to the index.html page but the alert box code is not being executed.I think the reason bcz out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.println("alert('password didn't matched ');");
 out.println("</script>"); is generating the alert box code for servlet not for the html page

Comment: Try to add alert message in JSP for reference Google it you will find many docs for same