# How to add a successful alert message in servlet code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

private void addstudentcontroler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String fname = request.getParameter("fname");

String lname = request.getParameter("lname");

String email = request.getParameter("email");

Studentenum sa = new Studentenum(fname, lname, email);

studentDAL.addstudent(sa);

String message = studentDAL.addstudent(sa);

if (message != null) {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('message');");
        out.println("</script>");
    }
response.sendRedirect("Studentcontroler");
```

}

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176684/how-to-show-alert-in-a-jsp-from-a-servlet-and-then-redirect-to-another-jsp) will help you to achieve the same.

Comment: I have tried all solutions but no luck any other alternate way or do I need to import any package